# Evento Onclick en botones creado dinamicamente

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick, onclicklistener

Estoy creando una tabla y a dos columnas les tengo que colocar unos botones de editar y eliminar pero lo que pasa es que la tabla se crea bien pero al presionar los botones no me encuentra el evento onclick.

Alguien sabe que es lo que puede estar pasando?

Cada vez que presiono los botones me aparece el error que coloco abajo.

He intentado con button, asp:button, linkbutton, a, etc y nada me detecta el onclik

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ObtenerActividadesColaborador();
    }

    public void ObtenerActividadesColaborador()
    {
        LogicaNegocioRequerimiento logicaNegocioRequerimiento = new LogicaNegocioRequerimiento();
        var Actividades = logicaNegocioRequerimiento.ObtenerListaActividadesColaborador("jramireza");
        StringBuilder Builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < Actividades.Count; i++)
        {
            Builder.Append("<tr>");
            Builder.Append("<td><asp:Button id='btnActualizar" + i + "' class='btn btn-primary' OnClick='btnActualizar_Click' runat='server' /><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Editar</td>");
            Builder.Append("<td><asp:Button id='btnBorrar" + i + "' class='btn btn-danger' OnClick='btnBorrar_Click' runat='server' /><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i> Borrar</td>");
            Builder.Append("<td>" + Actividades[i].IdRequerimiento + "</td>");
            Builder.Append("<td>" + Actividades[i].DscSistema + "</td>");
            Builder.Append("<td>" + Actividades[i].DeRequerimiento + "</td>");
            Builder.Append("<td>" + Actividades[i].CanTiempoAtencion + "</td>");
            Builder.Append("<td>" + Actividades[i].FecRegistroActividad + "</td>");
            Builder.Append("</tr>");
        }
        ListaActividades.InnerHtml = Builder.ToString();
    }

    protected void btnBorrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int c = 1;

    }

    protected void btnActualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int c = 1;

    }
```

ERROR

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: btnActualizar_Click is not defined at HTMLUnknownElement.onclick (Actividades:137)
```

Comment: Perdona, para crear los botones de forma dinámica. Porque no creas el botón directamente y posteriormente lo añades a la interfaz. A cada botón le asignaras un classid diferente para identificarlo y asignas a todos el método actualizar o borrar según toque?

Comment: @MarcosMuñozMorales Se supone que cuando lo creo, le asigno el id y le coloco el nombre del evento onclick es para eso mismo para que cuando presione el que dice ejemplo borrar vaya al evento onclick y ejecute lo que le vaya a programar ahi.

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo tuve que hacer con javascript,

asi cree el boton

```
 Builder.Append("<td><input type='button' class='btn btn-primary' value='Actualizar' id='BtnActualizar" + (i + 1) + "' onclick='btnActualizar_Click("+ Actividades[i].ConEncRegistroActividad + ")'</td>");
```

y

luego hice la funcion JS

function btnActualizar_Click(Id) {
           //CODIGO
        }

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes asignar el evento despues de crear el elemento:

```js
var i = 0;

$('#AddButton').click(function() {
   ++i;
   var newInput = '<input class="myFavoriteClass" type="submit" name="Boton[]" id="Boton-'+i+'" value="Boton '+i+'"> <br />';
    $('div').append(newInput);
});


    $(document).on("click", ".myFavoriteClass", function() {
       var inputID = $(this).attr('id');
       alert(inputID); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="AddButton">Agrega boton</button>

<br />
<br />

<div>
    <input type="submit" class="myFavoriteClass" name="Boton[]" id="Boton-0" value="Boton  0"> <br />
</div>
```